# Manipulating Text Position CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, image, text

I am constructing a vertical navigation bar unable to format the text next to the image as I'd like. I can manipulate the image using the margin. I've got it where I want it. Now, I try to manipulate the text margin and it has no effect. It appears like so....

[image: Example]

HTML:

```
<div class="content_nav">
  <div class="content_nav_item"><a href="#"><img src="images/icon.jpg" height="60px" width="60px" alt="One"><span class="content_nav_item_text">One</span></a></div>
  <div class="content_nav_hr">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="content_nav_item"><a href="#"><img src="images/icon.jpg" height="60px" width="60px" alt="One"><span class="content_nav_item_text">One</span></a></div>
  <div class="content_nav_hr">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="content_nav_item"><a href="#"><img src="images/icon.jpg" height="60px" width="60px" alt="One"><span class="content_nav_item_text">One</span></a></div>
  <div class="content_nav_hr">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="content_nav_item"><a href="#"><img src="images/icon.jpg" height="60px" width="60px" alt="One"><span class="content_nav_item_text">One</span></a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content_nav{
margin:45px 0px 45px 48px;
padding:0px;
width:232px;
height:467px;
background-color:#82c738;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px #578e30;
float:left;
}
.content_nav_item {
margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
padding:0px;
height:115px;
}
.content_nav_hr {
margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
padding:0px;
height:1px;
width:202px;
background-color:#A0DF5C;
}

.content_nav_item_text {
margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
padding:0px;
}
.content_nav_item img {
margin:28px 10px 0px 20px;
padding:0px;
display:inline;
}
```

Any thoughts as to why I can't position that span?

Comment: Try to change the bottom padding value of your text. ;)

Comment: @Depado Hmmm... it responds to padding values horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: What about the padding-bottom and padding-top properties ?

Answer (score 1):

Text is kindof a weird bird in CSS, it's not handled how you'd think or want it to be. [Here's a good article](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) explaining the idiosyncrasies of vertical text alignment

Comment: I believe I follow the article but I am having no success. Using method 1... I have a set height for the container (.content_nav_item) and changed the span to a div. This meets the requirements outlined in the article. I then added ` position:absolute; height:18px; top:50%; margin-top:-9px;`. Now all 4 divs containing text are lumped right on top of each other. Also, the margin does not affect the position.

Answer (score 0):

The text is between `span` tags. This tags is between the `a` tag and the `div` tag.
You need to separate them. They are stacking the text and they prevent the text to move.

You need to "end" the `img` tag

Comment: What if he wants to make his image and text clickable (I mean only one link for image and text) ? That would force hime to open two `<a>` tags...

Comment: So you have a different solution for that. You can surround them with div tag for example

Comment: That's exactly the reason I did it. I suppose that opening two `a` tags would be fine though.

Comment: Wrapping the entire div in `a` tags doesn't work (with respect to manipulating the text position).

Comment: I'm not recommended to use padding for text position, it can acting different in each browser.